# gawk and PROCINFO not working as expected with sorting longer length strings

Tags: sorting, awk

Suppose I have a simple little file of strings that I want to sort by line length:

```
$ cat file1
123
2
45
12345
123456789
1
```

I can write a `gawk` script that will sort these strings using a function and `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`:

```
$ gawk 'function cmp_len(i1, v1, i2, v2) {
            return length(v1) - length(v2)
      }
      NR==FNR{arr[$0]; next}
      END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "cmp_len"
      for (e in arr) print e
      } 
      ' file1
1
2
45
123
12345
123456789
```

Perfect!

But now suppose that I add some longer strings into that file:

```
$ cat file2
123
2
45
xyxyxyxyxyyxyxyxyxyxyyxyxyxxyxyxyxyyxyxyxyxyyx
12345
56565656565656565665656566565656656565656
123456789
1
```

It breaks:

```
$ gawk 'function cmp_len(i1, v1, i2, v2) {
            return length(v1) - length(v2)
      }
      NR==FNR{arr[$0]; next}
      END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "cmp_len"
      for (e in arr) print e
      } 
      ' file2
123456789
56565656565656565665656566565656656565656
1
2
45
123
12345
xyxyxyxyxyyxyxyxyxyxyyxyxyxxyxyxyxyyxyxyxyxyyx
```

It does work properly this way:

```
$ awk '{ print length()"\t"$0}' file2 | sort -n | cut -f2
# expected output by length...
```

But that makes the script I am writing more difficult.

Any ideas why `PROCINFO` is not working with longer strings in this example?

Comment: aside - you only have one input file so `NR==FNR` is always true and so could be removed.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks. The script I was working on had two, hence that was left over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal):

> Here, 'i1' and 'i2' are the indices, and 'v1' and 'v2' are the                                                       corresponding values of the two elements being compared.

Your comparison function is comparing the *values* of the array, not the *indexes*. And the values are always empty strings so the function always returns 0. Change it to

```
function cmp_len(i1, v1, i2, v2) {
         return length(i1) - length(i2)
}
```

and you'll get the order you want. Or better yet, cache the lengths and use a built-in comparison now that there's a meaningful value being stored:

```sh
gawk '
NR==FNR { arr[$0] = length($0) }
END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
        for (e in arr) print e
} 
' file1
```

Comment: So the first example output was just random goodness?

Comment: Since all entries compared equal to each other, yeah just chance it came out that way.